# bash script to manipulate text

Tags: bash, text

okay so i have a text file with the following info my.txt

```
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
```

i want to open the file grab the contents and manipulate each line then output it into a text called my2 file so it looks like this

```
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
```

can anyone help

Comment: side note, that is a pretty risky way of storing/sending passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Use a little awk script:

```
 awk -F: '{printf "http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=%s%%3A%s\n", $1, $2}' < my.txt > my2
```

Answer (score 1):

Very basic on bash:

```
while IFS=":" read u p
do
  echo "http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=$u%3A$p"
done < my.txt > my2.txt
```

#### Test

```
$ while IFS=":" read u p; do echo "http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=$u%3A$p"; done < file > my2.txt
$ cat my2.txt
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
```

Comment: okay can u set this up so it reads from my.txt and saves to my2.txt

Answer (score 1):

**Using `sed`: *You can use `-i` option to do infile substitutions or redirect to a new file***

```
$ sed 's,\(.*\):\(.*\),http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=\1%3A\2,' my.txt > my2.txt
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
```

**Using `awk`:**

```
$ awk -F: '{print "http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account="$1"%3A"$2}' my.txt > my2.txt
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=user%3Apass
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; ($user, $pass) = split /:/;
  print "http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=$user%3A$pass\n"' my.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Does what you want and discards lines with empty fields (e.g., empty lines):

```
while read l; do
    [[ $l =~ .+:.+ ]] || continue
    printf "http://mysever.com/2/tasks.php?account=%s\n" "${l/:/%3A}"
done < my.txt > my2.txt
```

*Caveat.* Make sure the passwords don't contain any funny symbols.