# bash curl array from text file

Tags: arrays, bash, curl

I have a text file named 2.txt with links in like this

```
www.link.php/user=1pass=3
www.link.php/user=1pass=3
www.link.php/user=1pass=3
www.link.php/user=1pass=3
www.link.php/user=1pass=3
```

I want to make a curl command that visits each link line by line and posts the part of the source I need; here's the source when one of the links is visited:

```
 online - Checked user : test cpu cooling rate: 0.50<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="tasks.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="account" placeholder="username:password" style="text-    align: center" /> <br />
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Check Account" />
      </form>
</body>
```

I want it to grab the source and remove all the html code apart from what is before `<html>` tag

so i end up with a text file like this

```
online - Checked user : test cpu cooling rate: 0.50
online - Checked user : test cpu cooling rate: 0.520
online - Checked user : test cpu cooling rate: 0.1150
online - Checked user : test cpu cooling rate: 6.50
```

can anybody help me do this please?

Comment: why do questions have to begin with `okay`?

Comment: Have you tried writing a script yet? What does it do?

Comment: Which part do you need help with?  Getting the data or parsing it?  If you need help parsing it, can you put up a better sample?  You didn't post valid HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will do what you want:

```
#!/bin/sh

output_file='3.txt'

while read line ; do
  curl "$line" | tr -d '\n' | sed -e :a -e 's/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba' >> "$output_file"
done < '2.txt'

exit 0
```

*Thanks to [Blackbit](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3014/regex-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-file) for the regex*.

Comment: woul you be able to lay it out for me bro my text file 2.txt holds the urls on each line then i want the results to 3.txt

Comment: Done! Just save the script in the right directory and launch it.

Comment: i get thiss error bro   curl : (3) <url> malformed

Answer (score 0):

Will the text before `<html>` always be on the same line as the tag? If so, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat url_list | while read url; do
  curl "$url" | grep "<html>" | sed 's/<html>.*//'
done
```

Replace `cat url_list` with your preferred solution for your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17365023/1630171).

Comment: no normaly the <html> tag is next to the line

Comment: What do you mean by "next to the line"? Is it on the same line or the next line? Is the preceeding text on a single line or can it span multiple lines?